# Caching python web requests for offline use

Tags: python-2.7, caching, python-requests

Is there a way to "cache" the requests I make with the python "requests" module in a way that even if I go offline the module still returns the webpage as if I was online? How can I achieve something like this? Currently I only found caching libraries that just cache the webpage but you still have to be online...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone else searching, the module that does the job is called "vcrpy".

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use request_cache module available.

Please check http://requests-cache.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html

Once you cache using request_cache data is available even if you are disconnected.

Comment: It only does "get" requests. It doesn't cache "post" results.